# SQL sum over(partition) not subtracting negative values in SUM

Tags: sql

I have the following query which outputs a list of transactions per user - units spent and units earned - column 'Amount'.

I have managed to group this per user and do a running total - column 'Running_Total_Spend'.

However it is ADDING the negative 'Amount' values rather than subtracting them. Sp pretty sure it is the SUM part of query not working.

```
WITH cohort AS(
    SELECT DISTINCT userID FROM events_live WHERE startDate = '2018-07-26' LIMIT 50),

    my_events AS (
    SELET events_live.* FROM events_live WHERE eventDate >= '2018-07-26')

    SELECT cohort.userID,
    my_events.eventDate, 
    my_events.eventTimestamp, 
    CASE
--spent resource outputs a negative value ---working
    WHEN transactionVector = 'SPENT' THEN -abs(my_events.productAmount)

--earned resource outputs a positive value ---working
    WHEN transactionVector = 'RECEIVED' THEN  my_events.productAmount END AS Amount,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cohort.userID ORDER BY cohort.userID, eventTimestamp asc) AS row,
--sum the values in column 'Amount' for this partition
--should sum positive and negative values ---NOT WORKING--converting negatives into positive
--------------------------------------------------
    SUM(CASE WHEN my_events.productAmount >= 0 THEN my_events.productAmount
    WHEN my_events.productAmount <0 THEN -abs(my_events.productAmount) end) OVER(PARTITION BY cohort.userID ORDER BY cohort.userID, eventTimestamp asc) AS Running_Total_Spend
---------------------------------------------------
    FROM cohort
    INNER JOIN my_events ON cohort.userID=my_events.userID
    WHERE   productName = 'COINS' AND transactionVector IN ('SPENT','RECEIVED')
```

Comment: I think `abs` function is causing the error here.

Comment: tried changing it to **-1*(my_events.productAmount)** - still not summing correctly

Comment: I don't know why you are even using case for Sum function. SQL will handle the negative amount. Get rid of Case in sum function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you want that logic around `transactionvector` for the sum too as `my_events.productamount` seems to be always positive.

```
...
sum(CASE
      WHEN transactionvector = 'SPENT' THEN
        -my_events.productamount
      WHEN transactionvector = 'RECEIVED' THEN
        my_events.productamount
    END) OVER (PARTITION BY cohort.userid
               ORDER BY cohort.userid,
                        eventTimestamp) running_total_spend
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your sum function to -

```
SUM(my_events.productAmount) OVER(PARTITION BY cohort.userID ORDER BY cohort.userID, eventTimestamp asc) AS Running_Total_Spend
```